# поиск файлов на сервере с помощью Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

для примера, есть сервер .1 и .2

на сервере .1 мне нужно запустить скрипт который найдет определенные файлы, и сверит эти файлы, с файлами на сервере .2, если файлы уже есть на сервере .2 то на сервере .1 их нужно удалить
и все это мне жестко нужно написать на python

вот пример проверки файлов который я написал и запускаю у себя на компьютере, но работает он криво

```
DIRECTORY_FILE = 'C:/test/1/'
DIRECTORY_FILE_SERVER = ['C:/test/50/TEST@ONLINE/sent/', 'C:/test/50/TEST@LOG/sent/']

def preparation(find, direct1, direct2):
    file_smb = []
    file_alltime = []
    for i in find:
        x = glob.glob(pathname=i, root_dir=direct1)
        if x:
            file_smb.append(x)

    for dirs in direct2:
        for i in find:
            z = glob.glob(pathname=i, root_dir=dirs)
            if z:
                file_alltime.append(z)
                return file_alltime
    return file_smb, file_alltime


print(preparation(WHAT_FIND, DIRECTORY_FILE, DIRECTORY_FILE_SERVER))
```

мне с этой функции нужно получить 2 списка файлов (с сервера .1 и .2) которые я буду дальше обрабатывать и сверять другой функцией

вот пример как файлы лежат у меня в тестовой сборке (1 - это условно сервер .1 а 50 - условно сервер .2)

```
C:/test/1/TEST@LOG-2022-12-04.7z 
C:/test/1/TEST@LOG-2023-02-05.7z 
C:/test/1/TEST@ONLINE_LOG-sent-20230329.zip 
C:/test/1/TEST@ONLINE_LOG-sent-20230331.zip

C:/test/50/TEST@ONLINE/sent/TEST@LOG-2022-12-04.7z 
C:/test/50/TEST@ONLINE/sent/TEST@LOG-2023-02-05.7z
C:/test/50/TEST@ONLINE/sent/TEST@LOG-2023-04-09.7z

C:/test/50/TEST@ONLINE/sent/TEST@ONLINE_LOG-sent-20230329.zip
C:/test/50/TEST@ONLINE/sent/TEST@ONLINE_LOG-sent-20230330.zip
C:/test/50/TEST@ONLINE/sent/TEST@ONLINE_LOG-sent-20230331.zip
C:/test/50/TEST@ONLINE/sent/TEST@ONLINE_LOG-sent-20230401.zip
```

сейчас вроде бы вывод верный, но может есть решение лучше? и так же буду очень благодарен как это все подвести что бы в итоге я мог вместо этого:

```
'C:/test/50/TEST@ONLINE/sent/', 'C:/test/50/TEST@LOG/sent/'
```

подключаться и искать файлы на сервере - примерно по такому пути `'192.168.0.2/var/log/TEST@LOG/sent/'`

*текущий вывод программы:

```
([['TEST@LOG-2022-12-04.7z', 'TEST@LOG-2023-02-05.7z'], ['TEST@ONLINE_LOG-sent-20230329.zip', 'TEST@ONLINE_LOG-sent-20230331.zip']], [['TEST@ONLINE_LOG-sent-20230329.zip', 'TEST@ONLINE_LOG-sent-20230330.zip', 'TEST@ONLINE_LOG-sent-20230331.zip', 'TEST@ONLINE_LOG-sent-20230401.zip'], ['TEST@LOG-2022-12-04.7z', 'TEST@LOG-2023-02-05.7z', 'TEST@LOG-2023-04-09.7z']])
```

Большое спасибо за любую помощь